# Can't retreive href with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve hrefs in a for loop with with BeautifulSoup.
I have sorted out irrelevant parts of the HTML with some `find_all`. The most recent I have done is:

```
events = soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "event-link-wrap"})
```

I then run a for loop like this:

```
for event in events:
    href = event.find("href")
    category = event.find("p",{"class": "category"})
    title = event.find("h3")
    arena = event.find("span", {"class": "venue"})
```

When I print href I get `None`. Can it be that the href is in the class that I use `find_all` on? If I print `event` I get:

```
<a class="event-link-wrap" href="https://www.WHATIWANT.COM/HERE title="More Info">
<div class="thumb">
<img alt="pic_125x125.jpg" src="https://www.test.com/pic.jpg"/> </div>
<div class="info clearfix">
<p class="category">CATEGORY HERE</p>
<h3>EVENT TITLE HERE</h3>
<p class="date"><span class="m-date__rangeFirst"><span class="m-date__day"> 6 </span></span><span class="m-date__separator"> - </span><span class="m-date__rangeLast"><span class="m-date__day"> 7 </span><span class="m-date__month">april</span></span> <span class="venue"> ARENA HERE</span> </p>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
<span class="icon"></span>
<span class="icon-hover"></span>
</div>
</a>
```

The href I want is in the first tag. I am able to retrieve everything I want except for the href. How do I get the href? Like I mentioned, now all it returns is `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looping over the `<a>` tag which itself contains the `href` you are after, you can directly get the `href` using `href = event['href']`.

The `find()` method expects a tag as its first parameter and not an attribute. So, using `find('href')` anywhere in the code will always return `None`.

Simply use this:

```
for event in events:
    href = event["href"]
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the `href` by `__getitem__`:

```
events = [i['href'] for i in soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "event-link-wrap"})]
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
events = soup.find_all("a", class_="event-link-wrap")
for event in events:
    href = event.get("href")
```